# Why do we feel the present moment has already happened?

Tags: memory

When I'm with my friends at some place doing something or talking about something, suddenly a thought comes to my mind that this present moment has already happened previously. But when I try to remember it, nothing's there, no memory at all.

Can anyone explain why ?

Comment: [Déjà vu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu).